# Source URL of Facebook Likes for Likebox

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-likebox

My question is regarding the likebox from this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

I want to know specifically what pages are generating likes for my Facebook page. For example, are they coming from the home page, individual product pages, or blog? I want to remove the likebox from pages that aren't generating any 'likes'

I was looking at this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Is the `edge.create` event what I'm looking for here?

By the way, I know about the insights feature on Facebook where I can get stats on 'Like Sources'. I just want to know more specifically what URL's are being used for the Like Box.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The edge.create method will allow you to capture when someone clicks on the Like button so you can do your own recording. If you don't want to write your own tracking code, you can use Google analytics, which is far easier since they do almost everything for you. 
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to track which pages on my site are liked. I never thought of using Google analytics for this. I followed the instructions on this page: http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/how-to-track-tweets-facebook-likes-and-more-with-google-analytics/   But what I was really trying to do was track likes of my Facebook page ie 'facebook.com/companyname' That I still haven't been able to figure out. I'll do some more digging on your link